# Rewrite URL for nginx with language option

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have url `www.foo.com` which has two languages `EN` and `CN`. I have pages such as `about.php`, `product.php`, etc.

I want the URL `www.foo.com/about.php?lang=cn` to be written as `www.foo.com/cn/about` and same way, `www.foo.com/en/product`, etc.

I am using nginx for serving this php website.

I am able to hide the .php file as

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?$query_string;
}
```

I tried writing something like this

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/$query_string/ $uri.php?$query_string;
}
```

But somehow doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you try some thing like 

`location  / {
       if ($arg_lang){
         rewrite ^ /$arg_lang/$uri permanent;
       }
    }` ?

Comment: I have not tried. Can you elaborate ? I mean how can i assign lang="cn" value into $arg_lang, etc.

Comment: As far as I know nginx provides an $arg_<name> variable for every part of your query string. So $arg_lang should be available out of the box. So when lang is set within the query string the rewrite should take place. But in the moment I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Add .htaccess file in your folder.

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/about/?$    about.php?lang=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/product/?$    product.php?lang=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: nginx does not support a .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following. With this example you "loose" all other query arguments.

```
 location / {
        # for every query string parameter nginx provides a variable
        # $arg_<name>
        if ($arg_lang != ''){
          set $old_lang $arg_lang;
          set $args lang='';
          set $arg_lang '';
          # questionmark after $uri drops all query params
          rewrite ^ /$old_lang$uri? redirect; # or permanent
        }
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work. But, thanks I got to know about `$arg_` variable